# Error en la ejecución de comandos SFTPchannel is not opened

Tags: sftp

Tengo un programa que sube archivos a un servidor sftp al probar desde mi computadora funciona bien pero al probar en el servidor donde quedara el programa me envia este error:

> Error en la ejecucion de comandos SFTPchannel is not opened.

Este es el pedazo de coigo donde me envia el error:

```
channelSftp.connect(60000);
```

De verdad les agradeceria si pudieran ayudarme.

```
    public final void addFile(String ftpPath, String filePath,
        String fileName) throws IllegalAccessException, IOException,
        SftpException, JSchException {
        GenProcedimientos procedimientos = new GenProcedimientos();
        procedimientos.EscribeLog("Validando conexión a  SFTP");
        if (this.session != null && this.session.isConnected()) {
 
            // Abrimos un canal SFTP. Es como abrir una consola.
            procedimientos.EscribeLog("Abriendo canal SFTP");
            ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) this.session.
                openChannel("sftp");
 
            // Nos ubicamos en el directorio del FTP.
            procedimientos.EscribeLog("Ubicando ruta "+ ftpPath);
//            channelSftp.cd(ftpPath);
            procedimientos.EscribeLog("Conectando a ruta ");
            channelSftp.connect(60000);
            
            String ftpPathFinal = ftpPath+fileName;
            System.out.println(String.format("Creando archivo %s en el directorio %s", fileName, ftpPath));
            
            procedimientos.EscribeLog("Creando archivo %s en el directorio" + ftpPath);
            
            channelSftp.put(filePath, ftpPathFinal);
            
 
            System.out.println("Archivo subido exitosamente");
            procedimientos.EscribeLog("Archivo subido exitosamente: " + fileName);
 
            channelSftp.exit();
            channelSftp.disconnect();
        } else {
            procedimientos.EscribeLog("No existe sesion SFTP iniciada.");
            throw new IllegalAccessException("No existe sesion SFTP iniciada.");
        }
    }
```